# How i can use Router module from aiogram?

Tags: python, aiogram

I tried to connect to the bot in main.py code from /handlers/start.py but it didn't work out.
I use this code:

main.py

```
        bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
        dp = Dispatcher(bot)
        dp.middleware.setup(LoggingMiddleware())
        start_webhook(
            dispatcher=dp,
            webhook_path=WEBHOOK_PATH,
            skip_updates=True,
            host=WEBAPP_HOST,
            port=WEBAPP_PORT,
        )
        dp.include_router(start.router)
        await bot.set_webhook(WEBHOOK_URL)
```

/handlers/start.py

```
from aiogram.types import Message
from aiogram import Router


router = Router()


@router.message(commands=["start"])  # [2]
async def cmd_start(message: Message):
    await message.answer("Работаем")
```

But it gives this error:
`ImportError: cannot import name 'Router' from 'aiogram' (C:\Users\Sell\Documents\edatgshop\.venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\__init__.py)`
How i can fix this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have a version 2.x library installed, routers are in beta version 3.x
To do this, install the beta version.

```
pip install -U --pre aiogram
```

Answer (score 0):

You have circular importing problem. Perhaps, your `main.py` run one time when you start your programm, and at least one time after run, when some other script do `import main.py` or like this. this provokes the situation, that your `dp.include_router(start.router)` calls twice, and on second time its throw an error.

You should rework arcitecture of your project, at least make controlable init function in main.py, which you will excactly know when its run. Smth like this:

```
#...
#... all prev code ...

def init():
   dp.include_router(start.router)
   await bot.set_webhook(WEBHOOK_URL)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   init()
```